# socket.io vs pusher.com are reliable for a production app?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, dependencies, real-time

Maybe this question is not totally related with technical issue, but i have a question maybe that is helpful for me or many of us.

i am using socket.io for a messaging app, or there is a similar paid one pusher.com which allows same thing for messaging.

Now assume that i am using socket.io and i have installed all required dependencies and my app is running perfectly on my production server now the question is that is socket.io / Nodejs is dependent on any other 3rd party (external) library which is not on my server ? like if something changed at socket.io library or Nodejs level will that effect my app or project ? if socket.io project closed for some reason will that stop my running app ?

i just wanted to confirm the dependencies on these type of libraries / modules.

please suggest.

Comment: Well if it's the best one in the market and you can't create a better one yourself, it is as reliable as it gets

Comment: and socket.IO is indeed the best option in my opinion so rest is up to you